# (git) Bash: clone and checkout a specific env

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I'm trying to do the following with a single git bash script:

1. cloning a git repo
2. going into the subfolder where the repo has been cloned
3. switch to another branch (env/dev)
4. do a git pull for good measure
5. go back to the previous folder

I plan to call it as `./clone.sh https://myserver.com/foo/blabla.git`

I currently have:

`git clone $1 && basename $1 .git|xargs cd && git checkout env/svil && git pull && cd ..`

this though gives an error: `xargs: cd: No such file or directory` after the repo has been cloned. Where am I going wrong and how can I solve this?

please do mind that I don't have a full bash at my disposal, only git bash

Thanks

Comment: What is the script supposed to do that `git clone --branch …` doesn’t do?

Comment: `xargs cd` will change directory in a subshell only.  The caller of `xargs` will not change directory.

Comment: @Biffen oops maybe you're right.

Comment: @William Pursell, nothing there

Comment: (One nice thing about scripts is that you don‘t have to make oneliners. You could use `set -e` and get rid of all the `&&`s. (And that last `cd ..` is superfluous.) And [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.)

Comment: @Biffen `set -e` has [its own pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). I personally do not use it.

Comment: You don't have an external program named `cd`, and if you had, it would be of no use to do a _cd_ inside the child process spawned by _xargs_. Note that your _xargs_ is **only** running `cd` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the current working directory to `<repo_dir>/.git` so as to execute your `git` commands, `cd` must be a shell built-in; this cannot be an executable you will find on your disk.

This is because changes made by an executable to its environment (current working dir, environment variables, limits, etc.) have no effect on the calling process (your shell). Thus, even if you had an external `cd`, like with any command found on your disk, your directory change would be immediately cancelled when your `cd` command exits, which would defeat its purpose.

You should instead write:

```
git clone "$1" \
&& cd "$(basename "$1" .git)" \
&& git checkout env/svil \
&& git pull \
&& cd ..
```

Notes:

- by default, you should double-quote parameter expansion (`$1` or `$foo`); I did it for you
- with `git -C <repo_dir>` you wouldn't need to change the current directory

Comment: Nearly correct. In a normal installation, you **do** have a `cd` executable (try a `type -a cd`), but the OP said that he doesn't have a complete installation, so the _cd_ executale is missing. But you are right that it would be pointless to use it. A good use of /usr/bin/cd is to check whether you possibly could change into a directory, without actually changing your pwd: `if ! command cd foo; then; echo foo is not chdir-able; fi`.

Comment: @user1934428 « In a normal installation, you do have a `cd` executable »: as I explained in my answer, an external program that changes your current directory makes no sense at all in a Posix environment. `cd` **must** be a shell builtin because this is the only way a command can change it's parent's environment. If you have an external executable called `cd`, then it does something else than `chdir()` to the directory given in parameter.

Comment: Actually, doing a `command chdir`, or perhaps a `/bin/chdir` (depends on your platform), does internally a _chdir_, and sets the exit code accordingly. Of course your PWD does not change, but you can make use of the exit code. Just try it! Of course it is **also** a shell buitlin. That's why I said you have to do a `type -a cd` to see all definition. Just doing a `type cd` would not reveal it.

Comment: @user1934428 I really don't understand your point. OP's issue is that they try to call an executable called `cd` through `xargs` in order to change the current directory of their shell. This is not possible, changing your current working directory can only be done through a shell builtin. If you have a `/bin/chdir`, that command will not change the current directory of your shell. Just try it. So no, your first sentence «  Nearly correct. In a normal installation, you do have a cd executable » is wrong. As I said in my answer, in a normal installation `cd` is a shell built-in.

Comment: Indeed, this is not possible. That's why I wrote _it would be pointless to use it_. However the reason for the **error message** is not that - in general - a `cd` executable would not exist. In general it exists, but it is not installed in the user's PATH. My only objection was about you writing "cd is not an executable that you will find on your disk". Everything else you wrote is fully correct.

Comment: I maintain the assertion I made in my answer: `cd` (as used by the OP, i.e. to change the current dir to `.git`) **cannot** be an executable you will find on your disk. You replied that in a *normal* installation you have a `cd` executable; this is wrong. You then added that the reason why the OP doesn't find `cd` on their disk is that « OP said that he doesn't have a complete installation, so the cd executale is missing » and again this is wrong. The OP has a complete installation and the `cd` executable is missing because their is no point in having one. Where did you find a `cd` executable?

Comment: Well, what is a normal installation? The cd executable is on my MacOS by default, and on my Linux distribution ("Elementary Linux"), and back then when I used Cygwin on Windows, it was there as well. On my Mac, it is /usr/bin/cd. What OS are you using? Did you actually try my `type -a ...` command, which I suggested?

Comment: However you are right that not every Linux distribution provides an external `cd`. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) thread discusses this issue.

Comment: « what is a normal installation? » It's up to you to define the term you use :-) Your link to the U.SE discussion is *very* interesting. It shows that an external `cd` executable is here to provide a subset of the `cd` functionalites, in order to be`exec()`-ed by commands like `find`. BUT they are absolutely not provided for the primary function of `cd`: changing the current working dir, precisely what the OP is doing. To answer your question, no Debian-based distribution I use (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint) provides a `/bin/cd`. That doesn't make them an incomplete distro.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for this discussion, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What I find confusing, is, if you follow the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50025/5377) in the  aforementioned discussion, that there seems to be a consensus in that a POSIX-compatible discussion should provide a `cd` binary. I checked the POSIX-pages and could **not** read out of it that such a binary is needed. Hence I tend to agree with you that such a distro is not necessarily incomplete.

Comment: In case you are interested: [Here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap01.html#tag_23_01_07)  is an example for the use case of a `cd` binary (see the `find` command near the start of the page).